# Artificially create Cassandra error to test retry policy

Tags: database, cassandra, integration-testing, datastax, gocql

How might you force a Cassandra error that triggers a retry policy?

According to the DataStax, the following errors trigger a retry policy:

- Read and write timeouts.
- When the coordinator determines *there are not enough replicas to satisfy a request*.

Edit: The driver I'm using is called gocql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggle the network connection of a node off, and it will appear momentarily down. Any request that needed that node to satisfy the consistency level, or if that node was the co-ordinator of the query will need to retry.

Comment: Note that the retry policy will only kick in for idempotent queries. This can be configured in the Java driver on Statements. https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/idempotence/

Comment: In this instance, the OP is using the gocql driver, although that is only known from another question - but you are correct also for that driver, it does check idempotence.

Comment: Andrew, for a single node cluster running in a Docker container, would a simple restart of the container produce the affect you describe? I tagged gocql in this question, but did not specify it as the driver I'm using. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: It should cause a retry, assuming the statement is considered idempotent.